# Binding keys in xbindkeysrc to type a command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xbindkeys, keyboard-event

I am trying to bind `Alt+Up` to type `cd ..` command using Xbindkeys. Here is what I've tried, among other things:

```
"sleep 1 && xdotool type cd .. --delay 15 && xdotool key Return"
Alt+Up
```

I can't make it work, although other commands (like `slock`) work with this key combination. Is there anything wrong about this approach?

Comment: I don't think xbindkeys interprets commands as shell expressions. Try `"bash -c 'sleep 1 && xdotool type date --delay 15 && xdotool key Return'"` as the command?

Comment: @kba Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the details but one problem could be that the Alt modifier is still active when xdotool sends the keystrokes. Also you have the `--delay` option too late in the arg list.  I managed to get this working:

```
"sleep .1 && xdotool type --clearmodifiers --delay 15 date && sleep .1 &&  xdotool key --clearmodifiers Return"
  Alt+Up
```

You can replace `date` by `'cd ..'`.